# use gamedev as support channel for game framework?

Tags: support

We are considering to use gamedev.stackexchange.com as the primary support channel for the html5 game framework [craftyjs](http://craftyjs.com). Would this be appropriate? Look at our [google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/craftyjs) to get an idea of the kind of questions.

Answer (score 4):

As long as they're not "general javascript" questions that would be better suited to SO I don't see why not.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be appropriate. But answering the same questions on SO (where they would fit too) instead could give you more visibility. When a developper has a programming problem, he will naturally go to SO first, even if he is developping with a game frameword.